# Pages change the words after exporting as PDF

Tags: pdf, pages

As we know, most companies have their NLP applications to analyze the resumes they receive.
I recently noticed that if you export your PDF using Pages, the actual content will be changed after exporting to PDF.

For example, I have "Computer Software Engineering" on my Pages; you can see in the PDF file it is the same. Still, if you want to copy this sentence, it will be "Computer SoCware Engineering." after you paste the content in a text editor.
So it will confuse pdf processor NLP application when you want to find a job.

How should I stop pages from making changes like this to my pdf files? please don't tell to use Microsoft word

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Can you link to a Pages file with this problem?

Comment: Not seen this and have made many pdf files from Pages, Word and Excel.

Answer (score 1):

My first thought is that this is a font encoding error, caused by the inference of an '**ft**' ligature character. However, that's an uncommon ligature in most fonts, which usually only have **fi**, **fl**, and **ff**.

Normally, a PDF from Pages or other app should retain the underlying pair of characters that the ligature represents.

So, I would first check that you have really typed 'ft' in so**ft**ware; then perhaps try a different font.

Comment: I'd test a different font too - just in case.